# Styling from separate CSS files not applied with new components

Tags: css, reactjs

I have been trying to build a small project with React for the past few days and all went great until today. For some reason, no CSS is applied to new components! All the CSS that worked before is still up and running but if I'd add something like a `div` in between an already existing `div`, the new `div` will not pick up any CSS!
Example:

```
<div className="DivStyle"> // Styling applied!
  <div className="DivStyle"> </div> // Styling completely ignored!
<div>
```

It is probably worth mentioning that I am still able to style the components inline.
Also, looking at the sources in Chrome, the styles are uploaded!
Here is my concrete example:

```
import '../styles/drawers.css';

class BottomFilterDrawer extends React.Component<IBottomFilterDrawerProps, IBottomFilterDrawerState> {

    ...
    public render() {
        return(
            <Drawer
            open={this.state.isOpen}
            anchor="bottom"
            // tslint:disable-next-line jsx-no-lambda
            onClose={() => this.toggleDrawer(false)}>
              <div className="BottomDrawerContainer" style={{margin: "10px"}}> // Styling for "BottomDrawerContainer" class not applied! 
                ...
              </div>
            </Drawer>
        );
    }
}
```

The CSS file:

```
#BottomDrawerContainer {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

I am certain that the import path is correct, Typescript wouldn't even let me run it if it weren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying css for class not for id.
 So your css must be like below.

```
.BottomDrawerContainer {
   margin: 10px;
}
```

if you want to apply for inner div.

```
.DivStyle .DivStyle {
  //style for inner div
 }
```

Comment: Woops, gotta get some sleep I guess

Answer (score -2):

do not use again same id, React create error and if show any error first you solve error otherwise browser not show anything